# Powerapps Canvas - Decode Base64 encoded string to actual string

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am working with a canvas app which is reading query parameters from URL and displaying it in a form. Currently, I am trying to read a base64 encoded string and decode it to it's actual value. Is there a way to do this within the app itself, as I don't see a function which I can use? Is there a way I can do this via MS Flow because it needs a trigger like click, I wish to do this on page load?

Comment: This post on the PA Ideas forum unfortunately makes it sound like Base64 decoding is only present for media (images, audio, video, etc), and not available for general purpose text decoding: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/Native-base64-encode-decode/idc-p/457432/highlight/true#M29378

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We implemented this using an Azure function which was called on the powerapp load and it returned the decoded string back.

In fact, this is also how we have implemented a custom logger to be called for failures.